# What should we do about the [java.net.http] tag versus the [java-http-client] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I use the [java.net.http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.net.http) tag to cover questions which use the new Java package of that name, introduced in JDK 11.

But there also exists a [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client) tag which seems to have a magnetic attraction to such questions even though its tag wiki says that it relates to JDK 9 (which offered a non-finalised incubator package, which differs in numerous little ways from the final JDK 11 package).

I've been editing questions to add the [java.net.http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.net.http) tag to questions which relate to the new JDK 11 package, and removing the older tag if it's clear that it does not relate to the older version. But the [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client) tag seems to continue to be the popular go-to tag for new questions even if they relate to the new JDK 11 package.

Should we continue to edit questions to have them use [java.net.http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.net.http) instead of [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client)? Or should the tag wiki for [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client) simply be edited to allow it to apply to both the experimental JDK 9 package and the finalised JDK 11 package?

Comment: No matter what the tag wiki says, I'm pretty sure a good portion of users are just going to go with whatever comes up first as a match. It might be a visibility problem.

Comment: The official name of the JDK 11 module is "HTTP Client and WebSocket APIs". Its actually confusing that `java-http-client` *isn't* the proper name for that, because at first glance, the name perfectly matches. Maybe its time to re-think how the tags are named to make it easier to find the right tag? The  JDBC™ API  is tagged `jdbc` and *not* `java.sql`. In fact, using the package name isn't done for the 30 most popular tags for Java.

Comment: Other tags are [apache-commons-httpclient], [apache-httpclient-4.x], [java-http-client], or [angular-httpclient] - none of those uses a package name.

Comment: IIRC we renamed [java.util.stream] to [java-stream], for another example.

Comment: Do we even need a new tag for each new Java (or whichever language) package? Are there `java.net.http` questions that aren't covered by the `java` tag? Seems just as useless as some .NET tags like [tag:console.writeline] (really, a tag for a single method?????)

Comment: The new java.net.http package does introduce an entirely new way of operating with HTTP, and I do feel that a tag dedicated to this package is sensible. Obviously the `java` tag also applies to these questions, but Java is such a large collection of technologies that it seems useful to partition the major modules.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Definitely not for every standard JDK package. in this case I'm on the fence since there are also popular packages in the form of Apache HttpClient and OkHttpClient. The specific tag is helpful in pinpointing which exact one is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The official name of the JDK 11 module is "HTTP Client and WebSocket APIs". Its actually confusing that [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client) isn't the proper name for that, because at first glance, the name perfectly matches. Maybe its time to re-think how the tags are named to make it easier to find the right tag? *The JDBC™ API* is tagged [jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdbc) and not [java.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.sql).

Java tags almost never use package names and other HTTP clients have tag names like  [apache-commons-httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons-httpclient), [apache-httpclient-4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpclient-4.x), [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client), or [angular-httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-httpclient).  [java.util.stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.util.stream) was renamed to [java-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-stream).

Using [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client) for an incubator package without intending to use it for the final version of the API was a mistake, since that is a perfectly general name and restricting it to the incubator version leads to the problems of discoverability (as we see now).

As of now, the [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client) tag has 27 questions, almost half (13 to be precise) of them are already about the JDK11 package. Retagging the remaining 14 with an appropriate tag (e.g. [java-http-client-jdk9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client-jdk9)) that reflects that these questions are about the incubator package should be rather trivial, so I would suggest doing so and updating [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client) to be used for the new, official "HTTP Client and Websockets APIs".

Or we question whether it is necessary to have a tag for only 14 questions, just update [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client) to be used with JDK 11 and simply remove it from the questions where its about JDK9 & 10.

Comment: The reasoning here is sound, so I've edited the [tag:java-http-client] tag wiki to describe handling of both JDK 11 and the earlier incubator versions of the new API. Assuming that edit gets accepted, I'll then retag all [tag:java.net.http] instances as [tag:java-http-client] to tidy things up.

Comment: @Bobulous Sounds fine to me, sadly I lack the 5k to approve it right away. I had hoped more people would chime in here on Meta...

Answer (score -10):

By your own evidence and comments by others, [java-http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-http-client) is ambiguous and shall be disambiguated and removed.

Comment: Do you mean "should", here, rather than "shall", or is it your intent to issue a decree?

Comment: @MarkAmery https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/shall

Comment: I... know what the word "shall" means. Your link hasn't answered my question.

Comment: @ivan (from your link) _"used to emphasize that something will definitely happen"_ ... so you mean that this will happen whether there's a discussion around it or not?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I'm pretty sure this will happen, simply because it's the optimal solution. I'm not opposed to a discussion in any way, only expressing my confidence that there's nothing to discuss here, really.